# Búsqueda ficheros en windows .bat

Tags: windows, cmd

Estoy buscando la forma de listar unos ficheros con una extensión determinada, en una subcarpeta concreta, es decir:

```
Directorios: 
a>a1>a2
b>b1>b2

Siendo b   Carpeta
   |  
   |b1  Sub Carpeta
   - |
     |
     |b2 Sub
     -
```

Quiero listar todos los *.txt que estén en la carpeta que contenga "1".

Lo estoy haciendo con:

```
for /R C:\ /D %%v in (*1*) do (
   echo %%v
)
```

Asi obtengo los directorios, y asi busco los ficheros

```
for /R "C:\" %%f in (*txt) do (
                echo "%%f"
)
```

Claro que el ultimo me busca los *txt de todos los directorios.

He intentado hacer:

```
for /R C:\ /D %%v in (*1*) do (

   for /R %%v %%f in (*txt) do (
                echo "%%f"
   )
)
```

Lo que intentaba era pasar la ruta de %%v para que sea la búsqueda de ficheros.

Supongo que existirá alguna expresion para poder hacer esto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
for /f "delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:d "C:\*1*"') do (
  for %%f IN ("%%v\*.txt") do echo %%f
)
```

Comment: Funciona correctamente, excepto para los directorios con espacios en blanco.

Comment: Cierto. He añadido `"delims="` para sobreescribir los delimitadores que por defecto son el espacio en blanco y el tabulador.

Comment: Pues lo he probado con "delims=" y me sigue sin funcionar con directorios con espacios en blanco. Lo curioso es que si escribo las sentencias directamente en la consola si que me lista los directorios con espacios, incluso sin el "delims=". Seguiré investigando.

Comment: Faltaban las comillas dobles en `("%%v\*.txt")` para escapar los espacios en blanco :-)